# how to pass data coming from laravel query as a json object to the function in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, json, laravel, graph

i am actually using graphs in my project for which i am passing dynamic data from controller to blade and then in the js script. The js function in the blade accept the array of objects and i dont know how to assign the data from the controller to that js function.

```
$data['typesBasedProperties'] = DB::table('properties')
            ->join('property_types', 'properties.property_type', 'property_types.id')
            ->select('property_types.types as label', DB::Raw('COUNT(properties.id) as value'))
            ->whereIn('properties.id', $property_ids)
            ->groupBy('label')
            ->get()
            ->toJson();
```

and this is the js function

```
var donutChart = function(){
            Morris.Donut({
                element: 'morris_donught',
                data: [
                    {
                    label: " Download Sales ",
                    value: 12,
                    }, {
                    label: " In-Store Sales ",
                    value: 30
                    }, {
                    label: " Mail-Order Sales ",
                    value: 20
                    }
                ],
                resize: true,
                redraw: true,
                colors: ['#2b98d6', 'rgb(59, 76, 184)', '#37d159'],
                //responsive:true,
                
            });
        }
```

Comment: Can you share your controller code? And do you have api call from your js (frontend)? And can you dd your query result?

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to do something like this:

```
<script>
     var typesBasedProperties = {!! $typesBasedProperties !!}
</script>
```

After this you have `typesBasedProperties` object available in all your js code.

Check out [laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/blade#displaying-unescaped-data) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ajax request to fetch data from laravel controller to javascript or JQuery.

here's some example

controller

```
function bbq(Request $r){
    $data = DB::select('CALL bukubesar('.$r->no.')');
    $node = DB::select('CALL infonode('.$r->no.')');

    return array(
        'data' => $data,
        'node' => $node
    );
}
```

route (I'm using Group)

```
Route::controller(CPembukuan::class)->group(function () {
    Route::get ('/pembukuan-besar',          'bukubesar');
    Route::get ('/pembukuan-besar/query',    'bbq'      );
    Route::get ('/pembukuan-labarugi',       'labarugi' );
    Route::get ('/pembukuan-labarugi/query', 'lrq'      );
});
```

ajax (JQuery) on html or blade file

```
//a variable to pass to controller (optional)
val = $('#kode').val();

$.ajax({
    type: "get",
    url: "/pembukuan-besar/query",
    data: {
        'no': val // the data represented as 'no'
    },
    success: function(data) {
       console.log(data); // to view the data in console
       //do anything you want here
    }
});
```